# Fail a behat @javascript test when there is a javascript error on the page

Tags: javascript, behat

I need to write Behat tests to simply check for errors in Javascript. Nothing fancy, i just need to navigate to a page and fail the test if any error has been detected. I'm using Selenium. How could i do it?

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't, not ideally. That's really not what Behat is for. I would advise against it.